# Can you identify these heroes (wizards)?

Tags: character-identification

This is an image from the Polish games magazine "Top Secret #7" (published on October 1991).

[image]

I tried services like TinEye and images.google.com but with no luck.

Most likely it's a game or book cover.

Can you identify these heroes? Or what game/book they come from?

[image]

Comment: Guy on the left seems to have raided Ming the Merciless' closet

Comment: It doesn't seem to match any of the games reviewed in the magazine; https://archive.org/details/TopSecret07

Comment: @Valorum It also doesn't seem to match any games from #6 or #08

Comment: It could refer to the competition. There is a mention of the game "Demon's Kiss" (https://www.mobygames.com/game/demons-kiss), There you can find mage and Demon. Could be demon's name is Harpy.

Comment: Skąd idą święta?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is [*Celtic Legends*](https://www.lemonamiga.com/games/details.php?id=245) on the Amiga (or more specifically, artwork from a poster advert for the game).

[image]

The characters on the cover appear to correspond to two characters [mentioned in the blurb](https://www.lemonamiga.com/games/docs.php?id=304);

> 'Eskell' the blue and 'Sogrom' the scarlet.

**Eskell**
[image]

**Sogrom**
[image]

Comment: And so "you play as a powerful wizard Eskel against the evil Demog" (http://www.indieretronews.com/2015/07/celtic-legends-classic-ubisoft-strategy.html)

Comment: + https://www.lemonamiga.com/games/docs.php?id=304

Comment: @YaroslavKornachevskyi - Good catch. I wasn't looking at the characters from the cutscenes, but the ones from the gameplay :-)

Comment: Just wanted to add link to youtube https://youtu.be/8ZEqMB7p9Vo?t=76 =)

Comment: Amazing, thank you so much!

Comment: @Tom - [You're very welcome](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3iYzyDQ3hQ)

Comment: Bicentennial man? Nice movie :)

Comment: Wait... the pictures are clearly related, but the characters have completely different facial hair! Did the magazine redraw the picture (and give the characters a shave) for some reason, or was the original artwork released in multiple versions?

Comment: @IlmariKaronen - This magazine seems to have had its in-house artists re-draw all sorts of pictures for their cover art.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen There seems to be multiple different covers for the game. On a different picture they look like on the cover of Top Secret: https://www.mobygames.com/game/amiga/celtic-legends/promo/promoImageId,459701/

Comment: @Tom - I like your picture better. I actually found it before, but didn't realise that the artwork was subtly different.